# Django on_delete=models.CASCADE not working when using related_name

Tags: python, django, orm, model

I have a model named Proposal which is related to the model Customer by two different fields. I want that if any of the related users gets deleted the proposal will also get deleted. However, the on_delete=models.CASCADE is not achieving that. I guess I could use a signal to trigger this behaviour but I want to know if there is a better way to make it work in Django 4.0.

```
class Proposal(models.Model):

    # foreign keys
    created_by_customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    accepted_by_customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='accepted_by_customer')
```

This is my test with Pytest:

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_delete_proposal_from_created_by_customer():  
    """ Deleting customer that created the proposal must delete proposal """

    created_proposal = random_proposal()
    buyer = random_customer()
    created_proposal.created_by_customer = buyer
    created_proposal.created_by_customer.delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. The test was wrong. You need to save both the current model and the related model when modifying a foreign key for the changes to be applied.

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_delete_proposal_from_created_by_customer():
    """ Deleting customer that created the proposal must delete proposal """

    created_proposal = random_proposal()
    buyer = random_customer()
    created_proposal.created_by_customer = buyer
    created_proposal.save()  # <----------
    created_proposal.created_by_customer.save()  # <----------
    created_proposal.created_by_customer.delete()

    assert True if Proposal.objects.all().count() == 0 else False
```